# Interrupt Coalescing vs softnet_stat time_squeeze

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I'm doing some testing to understand Interrupt Coalescing and ITR for my I210 NIC by sending 64B packets. I've enabled one rx queue for the NIC to push the processing on one core. As expected, the number of packets processed per interrupt increases with cpu (core) occupancy, reaching 20k packets per interrupt at 100% occupancy.

From reading the posts, I understand the NIC interrupts are disabled while softirq /NAPI that is handling the packets is processed. Having the igb poll size set to 64 and net_rx_action budget to 300, I've expected time_squeeze element of the softnet_stat for the respective core to be increased accordingly. I understand this by reading https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/#interrupt-handler and net_rx_action code.

Surprisingly (at least for me), the counter was the same as before the test. Can someone please explain this?

Thanks!
Dean